# Issue w/ partial payments, price set changes, pending refund status

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, partial-payments

Civi 4.6.20 and Civi 4.6.31 (tested in both, same behavior), Drupal 7

Here is the scenario:

- User is registered on back end for event with multiple price set fields (call them Room Choice, Tuition, and Fee) with a $0.00 payment entered, which leaves them with the full balance owed.
- User makes an initial payment toward the balance.
- User then changes their mind about their room choice, so the admin changes the selections on Room Choice and Fee.  This decreases the balance BUT - important - the user still owes significantly more than they have paid.

The contribution's status - even though the contact still owes more than they have paid - gets changed during step 3 above from Partially Paid to Pending Refund.  So when the user's payment for the remaining balance comes in, the admin cannot enter it because Civi won't allow a payment of that amount (since it's pending refund).

Except for the user owing more than would be refunded, this scenario resembles this discussion: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36408.0  I'm really unclear where to go with this, however, and how to advise my client.  This does not seem like logical behavior on Civi's part; I totally understand the Pending Refund status if the changes to the registration result in a negative balance paid, but in this case no refund should be processed - the contact simply owes less money than they did.

Any ideas on how I or my client can proceed with this in terms of workflow?

Thanks in advance.